# template function won't compile

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my template function

```
template<typename T> std::stringstream logging_expansion ( T const * value ){
    std::stringstream retval;
    retval = retval << *value;
    return retval;
}
```

Here is how i call it to use it

```
logging_expansion( "This is the log comes from the convinient function");
```

But the linker is telling me that it can not reference the function:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >     logging_expansion<char>(char const*)", referenced from:
  _main in WirelessAutomationDeviceXpcService.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I think you can literally write `return (std::stringstream() << *value);` in one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the implementation of template functions in header files or define the specialization in the header.

I'm assuming you currently have something like:

```
//header.h
template<typename T> std::stringstream logging_expansion ( T const * value );

//implementation.cpp
#include "header.h"

template<typename T> std::stringstream logging_expansion ( T const * value ){
    std::stringstream retval;
    retval = retval << *value;
    return retval;
}

//main.cpp
#include "header.h"

//....
logging_expansion( "This is the log comes from the convinient function");
//....
```

So you need to move the implementation to the header:

```
//header.h

template<typename T> std::stringstream logging_expansion ( T const * value ){
    std::stringstream retval;
    retval = retval << *value;
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting some compiler errors when trying to compile this, maybe your code has something different. Regardless, if you reach the linking phase, this should do it.

Comment: oh thank you. I think there are some error in my code that I am trying to copy the stringstream since it's not copyable. Anyways, the original problem has been resolved. I need to put all the template definition in the header files.

Comment: @NegativeZero yup, that's how templates work. The compiler generates code for each specialization the first time it is encountered, so it needs to have access to the code in the same translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code:
 * i don't think you intend to just add the first character of the string to your stream
    so `*value`  does not make much sense

- stringstream does not have a assignment operator or copy constructor
  so `retval = retval << *value` does not make sense either.

A common cause for missing template functions is that you forgot to instantiate your template in a .cpp file. you do that like this

```
template std::stringstream logging_expansion<char>( char const *value);
```